# How to combine some file to create an ssl certificate for apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I need help on a certificate.
Usually I use certbot to install ssl certificates on nginx, but now I have to install ssl on apache and I have four files.
One is a key file, one is a txt file, I think this is the leaf, then I have the root and the intermediate with crt extension.

I try to read some tutorial but I don't have any idea how to combine them

I understand that I have to add in the cfg

```
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/certificate.key
```

And I imaging that the key is my key file, but the crt? Is a bundle?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your main problem is that you do not know what certificates are contained in the files. You can use `openssl` to decorate those files with some human readable info:

```
openssl x509 -in <your_file> -inform pem -issuer -subject -startdate -enddate
```

Once you identified the files just concatenate them into one file from leaf to root (cf. [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#SSLCertificateFile)). You can leave OpenSSL's annotations, so that you can remember which certificate is which. The concatenated file is the argument of `SSLCertificateFile`.

Comment: I know, I have key, leaf, intermediate, root. I need to concatenate leaf - intermediate - root?

Comment: Yes, that's the order. You may omit the root if you wish.